# eclipse java How to insert a build timestamp

Tags: java, build, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Java for my project. And I want to display the buildtime to the user. How do I get Eclipse (or a plugin) to insert the build timestamp into a properties file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use either *maven*, or *ant*.
A quick google for maven and build timestamps returned [this](https://code.google.com/p/maven-timestamp-plugin/).

Maven is pretty good for also managing dependencies, etc, but it'll take some time to get used to it.  Ant is a bit easier, but just for building.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ant you can save the build timestamp to a properties file. Eg: If you have a properties file called project.props, in Ant you can define a target which can be run each time during the build:

```
<target name="buildtime">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="buildtime" pattern="yyyy MMMM dd HH:mm:ss" locale="en"/>
    </tstamp>

    <echo message="Current time and date: ${buildtime}" />
<!-- property name="buildtime" value="${buildtime}"/ -->
    <propertyfile file="project.props">
        <entry key="buildtime" type="date" value="${builltime}"  />
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

After the build, the property file will be updated with the build timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this particular problem (in Eclipse 3.8.1 debbuild) by adding a 'builder' .. [Project] --> Properties --> Builders --> New --> Program

Here I added a link to a bash script in my project directory that writes a properties file to my projects resources/properties folder, with key=value pairs for major, minor, svn revision, timestamp etc. Make sure the script builder is above the Java Builder.

In my project I read these properties into a version object when requested.

This works ok, although it is bizarrely erratic unless I select ALL the options under 'Run the builder:' in the 'Build Options' tab. Eclipse seems to store a lot of redundant state, especially about the file system. With these settings, the version is regenerated a lot, but that suits me. I have the same mechanism generating version properties for each module my project uses.

The biggest antifeature is the inability to trigger this behaviour when exporting a jar file. It would be good to have an option to trigger a clean/build before exporting.

Ps: I have a parallel  Ant build, independent of Eclipse, that uses the same bash script to generate the properties file. It doesn't suit me to use Ant or Maven from inside Eclipse.